# How to know the running state of a tor relay?

Tags: tor

For study purpose, I need to know whether a tor relay is running or not at a specific time in the past. Is it possible to get the information and how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP address of the relay, or can look it up in [relay search](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html), you can use [ExoneraTor](https://metrics.torproject.org/exonerator.html) can tell you if it was a relay on a specific date and time.

Comment: Thanks your comment. Now I know if I have the IP address of the relay, I can get  the running state of it through the "ExoneraTor" website. But the relay's IP address may change over time, so is there any way to get the running infomation by its more stable fingerprint?

Comment: If a relay changes IP but keeps it's fingerprint, you may need to search https://metrics.torproject.org/collector.html for older IP address information.  It is available there but I'm not sure any of the existing tools will show historical IP information.